# Is there any equivalent to Postgresql EVERY aggregate function on other RDBMS?

Tags: database, postgresql, rdbms

Documentation for EVERY aggregate:

**every(expression)** : true if all input values are true, otherwise false

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html

---

EVERY is semantically equivalent to COUNT(conditionIsTrue) = COUNT(*)

```
select person_id, 

    every(visited_site = 'http://stackoverflow.com') as visited_same_site_forever,

    count(case when visited_site = 'http://stackoverflow.com' then '^_^' end) 
    = count(*) as visited_same_site_forever2

from z
group by person_id
order by person_id
```

Output:

```
 person_id | visited_same_site_forever | visited_same_site_forever2 
-----------+---------------------------+----------------------------
        88 | f                         | f
     55327 | t                         | t
    256196 | f                         | f
```

Data source:

```
create table z(person_id int, visited_site varchar(100), datetime_visited timestamp);

insert into z values
(55327,'http://stackoverflow.com','Jan 1, 2010'),
(55327,'http://stackoverflow.com','Feb 14, 2012'),
(55327,'http://stackoverflow.com','May 1, 2012'),
(256196,'http://stackoverflow.com','February 1, 2012'),
(256196,'http://stackoverflow.com','February 2, 2012'),
(256196,'http://slashdot.org','May 2, 2012'),
(88,'http://theregister.co.uk','April 1, 2012'),
(88,'http://slashdot.org','April 2, 2012');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Emulating `EVERY()` with `CASE` and `SUM()`

In fact, [this article describes how `EVERY()` can be emulated via `CASE` and `SUM()`](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/18/a-true-sql-gem-you-didnt-know-yet-the-every-aggregate-function/). The following two statements are equivalent:

```
SELECT EVERY(id < 10)
FROM book

SELECT CASE SUM(CASE WHEN id < 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
         WHEN 0 THEN 1 
         ELSE 0 
       END
FROM book;
```

The same is true for the `EVERY()` window function:

```
SELECT 
  book.*, 
  EVERY(title LIKE '%a') OVER (PARTITION BY author_id)
FROM book

SELECT
  book.*,
  CASE SUM(CASE WHEN title LIKE '%a' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       OVER(PARTITION BY author_id)
    WHEN 0 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
  END
FROM book;
```

#### SQL Standard

The `SQL:2008` standard mentions the `EVERY` aggregate function:

```
10.9 <aggregate function>

[...]

<aggregate function> ::=
  COUNT <left paren> <asterisk> <right paren> [ <filter clause> ]
  | <general set function> [ <filter clause> ]
  | <binary set function> [ <filter clause> ]
  | <ordered set function> [ <filter clause> ]

<general set function> ::=
  <set function type> <left paren> [ <set quantifier> ]
  <value expression> <right paren>

<set function type> ::=
  <computational operation>

<computational operation> ::=
  AVG
  | MAX
  | MIN
  | SUM
  | EVERY
  | [...]
```

But "advanced" SQL standard features are not often implemented by databases. [Oracle 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions003.htm) for instance, doesn't support it, neither does [SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx).

With [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#N125CF), however, you may be more lucky. HSQLDB 2.x is very standards-compliant, also [MySQL knows the `BIT_AND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_bit-and) aggregate function, which is a non-standard alias to `EVERY()`, also supported by Postgres.

Note, some databases allow for writing user-defined aggregate functions, so you may as well implement `EVERY()` yourself.

Comment: This is the answer :-) MySQL could have renamed BIT_AND to BOOL_AND. Postgresql's EVERY is an alias for BOOL_AND, Postgresql has BIT_AND too. Tried MySQL BIT_AND now, it works. However, MySQL don't have proper boolean, but there's a duality between its integer and boolean, that's why its BIT_AND is functionally equivalent to BOOL_AND/EVERY anyhow. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Hao: Yes, those databases copy some ideas off one another, so you see the same similar functions floating around here and there

Comment: @Hao: Not sure if this is still important to you, but I've figured out a way to emulate `EVERY()` with `SUM()` and `CASE`...

Comment: @LukasEder Oracle 20c: [BIT_AND_AGG](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/BIT_AND_AGG.html#GUID-82497098-6D77-48D3-89EF-C1041BF8A258)  `SELECT BIT_AND_AGG(CASE WHEN visited_site = 'http://stackoverflow.com' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM book`