# PostgreSQL - select count(*) for rows where a condition holds

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count

I have the following table and some sample records in it:

```
  id  | attr1_id | attr2_id |      user_id      | rating_id | override_comment
------+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+------------------
 1    |      188 |      201 | user_1@domain.com |         3 |
 2    |      193 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         2 |
 3    |      193 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         1 |
 4    |      194 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         1 |
 5    |      194 |      201 | user_1@domain.com |         1 |
 6    |      192 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         1 |
```

The combination of (`attr1_id`, `attr2_id`, `user_id`) is `UNIQUE`, meaning each user can only create one record with a specific pair of attribute ids.

My goal is to count the number of rows where `rating_id = 1`, but only count each combiniation of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` only once, and only where there doesn't exist any other row (by other users) that have `rating_id > 1` and refer to the same `attr1_id` and `attr2_id`.
Note that the combination of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` can be switched around, so given these two records:

```
  id  | attr1_id | attr2_id |      user_id       | rating_id | override_comment
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  20  |       5  |       2  | user_1@domain.com  |         3 |
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  21  |       2  |       5  | user_2@domain.com  |         1 |
```

no row should be counted, as the rows refer to the same combination of `attr_ids` and one of them has `rating_id > 1`.

However, if these two rows exist:

```
  id  | attr1_id | attr2_id |      user_id       | rating_id | override_comment
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  20  |       5  |       2  | user_1@domain.com  |         1 |
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  21  |       2  |       5  | user_2@domain.com  |         1 |
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  22  |       2  |       5  | user_3@domain.com  |         1 |
```

all rows should only be counted as one, because they all share the same combination of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` and all have `rating_id = 1`.

My approach so far is this, but it results in no rows being selected at all.

```
SELECT *
FROM compatibility c
WHERE rating_id > 1
  AND NOT EXISTs
    (SELECT *
     FROM compatibility c2
     WHERE c.rating_id > 1
       AND (
             (c.attr1_id = c2.attr1_id) AND (c.attr2_id = c2.attr2_id)
             OR
             (c.attr1_id = c2.attr2_id) AND (c.attr2_id = c2.attr1_id)
           )
    )
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want pairs of attributes whose ratings are always "1".

This should give you the attributes:

```
select least(attr1_id, attr2_id) as a1, greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id) as a2,
       min(rating_id) as minri, max(rating_id) as maxri
from compatibility c
group by least(attr1_id, attr2_id), greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id)
having min(rating_id) = 1 and max(rating_id) = 1;
```

To get the count, just use this as a subquery:

```
select count(*)
from (select least(attr1_id, attr2_id) as a1, greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id) as a2,
             min(rating_id) as minri, max(rating_id) as maxri
      from compatibility c
      group by least(attr1_id, attr2_id), greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id)
      having min(rating_id) = 1 and max(rating_id) = 1
     ) c
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you. How would I be able to not only select the count(*), but instead select the c.id of the compatibilities that need rating yet?

Comment: Just put `min(c.id)`in the subquery and run it alone, without the outer query.

Comment: I misphrased - I meant to ask how to select all these distinct pairs of (attr1_id and attr2_id), that still need rating. Is this possible?

Comment: @doque . . . I think you should ask another question.

Comment: And so I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908868/postgresql-select-distinctcolumn1-column2-where-a-condition-holds

Answer (score 3):

> My goal is to count the number of rows where `rating_id = 1`, but only
> count each combiniation of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` only once, and
> only where there doesn't exist any other row (by other users) that
> have `rating_id > 1`.

#### Building on your original

Your original query was on the right track to exclude offending rows. You just had `>` instead of `=`, and the count was missing, yet.

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   compatibility c
   WHERE  rating_id = 1
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM   compatibility c2
      WHERE  c2.rating_id > 1
      AND   (c2.attr1_id = c.attr1_id AND c2.attr2_id = c.attr2_id OR
             c2.attr1_id = c.attr2_id AND c2.attr2_id = c.attr1_id))
   GROUP  BY least(attr1_id, attr2_id), greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id)
   ) sub;
```

#### Shorter and faster

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS ct
FROM  (
   SELECT FROM compatibility  -- empty SELECT list is enough for count(*)
   GROUP  BY least(attr1_id, attr2_id), greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id)
   HAVING max(rating_id) <= 1
   ) sub;
```

Similar to this [earlier answer with more explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26519157/939860).
`HAVING max(rating_id) <= 1` implements your requirement exactly.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6YBag6ib)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4430f0/1)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In Postgresql this do it. SQLFiddle nor working right now:

```
select count(*)
from (
    select least(attr1_id, attr2_id), greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id)
    from compatibility
    group by 1, 2
    having not bool_or(rating_id > 1)
) s
;
 count 
-------
     2
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `CASE .. WHEN` to re-arrange the attributes such that the smaller one is always first and the order on that. Example query to follow..

```
SELECT attrSmall, 
       attrLarge,            
       MAX(rating_id) as ratingMax
  FROM (
   SELECT CASE WHEN c.attr1_id < c.attr2_id 
               THEN c.attr1_id 
               ELSE c.attr2_id END as attrSmall,
          CASE WHEN c.attr1_id < c.attr2_id 
               THEN c.attr2_id 
               ELSE c.attr1_id END as attrLarge,
          c.rating_id
    FROM compatibility c) as c1
  GROUP BY atrrSmall, attrLarge
  HAVING ratingMax = 1
```