# PostgreSQL - Select distinct(column1, column2) where a condition holds

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, count, distinct

I have the following table and some sample records in it:

```
  id  | attr1_id | attr2_id |      user_id      | rating_id |
------+----------+----------+-------------------+-----------+
 1    |      188 |      201 | user_1@domain.com |         3 |
 2    |      193 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         2 |
 3    |      193 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         1 |
 4    |      194 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         1 |
 5    |      194 |      201 | user_1@domain.com |         1 |
 6    |      192 |      201 | user_2@domain.com |         1 |
```

The combination of (`attr1_id`, `attr2_id`, `user_id`) is `UNIQUE`, meaning each user can only create one record with a specific pair of attribute ids.

My goal is to select all distinct combinations of (attr1_id, attr2_id) where `rating_id = 1`, but only select each combiniation of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` only once, and only where there doesn't exist any other row (by other users) that have `rating_id > 1` and refer to the same `attr1_id` and `attr2_id`.
Note that the combination of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` can be switched around, so given these two records:

```
  id  | attr1_id | attr2_id |      user_id       | rating_id | override_comment
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  20  |       5  |       2  | user_1@domain.com  |         3 |
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  21  |       2  |       5  | user_2@domain.com  |         1 |
```

no row should be counted, as the rows refer to the same combination of `attr_ids` and one of them has `rating_id > 1`.

However, if these two rows exist:

```
  id  | attr1_id | attr2_id |      user_id       | rating_id | override_comment
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  20  |       5  |       2  | user_1@domain.com  |         1 |
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  21  |       2  |       5  | user_2@domain.com  |         1 |
------+----------+----------+--------------------+-----------+------------------
  22  |       2  |       5  | user_3@domain.com  |         1 |
```

all rows should only be counted as one, because they all share the same combination of `attr1_id` and `attr2_id` and all have `rating_id = 1`.

In addition, there is some joining and filtering by a joined table column which I'll leave out, but I thought I'd mention it anyway.

**SQL Fiddle isn't working for me right now, but I've [uploaded some sample data from the compatibility table.](https://gist.github.com/doque/46967b8feabd92c79f7b)**

My query so far is this:

```
SELECT distinct(a1, a2),
       a1,
       a2
FROM
  ( SELECT c.*,
           least(attr1_id, attr2_id) AS a1,
           greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id) AS a2
   FROM compatibility c
   JOIN attribute a ON c.attr1_id = a.id
   JOIN PARAMETER pa ON a.parameter_id = pa.id
   JOIN problem p ON pa.problem_id = p.id
   WHERE p.id = 1
   GROUP BY 1,
            2 HAVING NOT bool_or(rating_id > 1)) s;
```

In the sample, there are a total of 144 ratings. Each user has created 7 ratings that have a `rating_id > 1` and of those 14 ratings, 2 refer to the same set of (`attr1_id`,`attr2_id`).
Hence, the number I'm looking for would be `(77-12) = 65`. However, the result here seems to be `77-2 = 75`. So only rows where two ratings with the same attribute ids exist, are discarded.

I would also point out [my previous question for this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719223/postgresql-select-count-for-rows-where-a-condition-holds/26719298?noredirect=1#comment42366332_26719298) where I was asked to open a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you describe:

```
select least(attr1_id, attr2_id) as attr1, greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id) as attr2
from table t
group by least(attr1_id, attr2_id), greatest(attr1_id, attr2_id) 
having bool_and(rating_d = 1) ;
```

I don't understand the other tables in your query, because your start with a single table that has everything you need.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly it. I left the other tables in there just to show I was doing a JOIN, just in case that could have had any effect. My knowledge of Postgres is quite limited so I wasn't sure. Thanks again for all your help!